# Сборка под ARM. Библиотеки ARM на x86_64

Tags: linux, сборка, apt-get, arm

мне нужно собрать сторонний проект под armhf архитектуру на своем x86_64. тулчейн у меня есть. если собирать без каких либо фич, то никаких проблем нету, но есть фичи, которые необходимо включить при компиляции. эти фичи требуют стороних библиотек(одна из них Nut_SNMP). при попытке добавить armhf или armel репозиторий в apt вылезает ошибка. Подскажите, если кто знает, как можно решить эту проблему

```
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg               
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal Release                                    
Hit http://archive.debian.org wheezy Release                                   
Ign http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                           
Ign http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Hit http://archive.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.debian.org wheezy/main armel Packages                       
Hit http://archive.debian.org wheezy/main armhf Packages                       
Hit http://archive.debian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages                 
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main armel Packages                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe armel Packages        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US.UTF-8
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_US     
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en        
Err http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_US.UTF-8
Err http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe amd64 Packages   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Ign http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US.UTF-8
Ign http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Ign http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_US.UTF-8
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/quantal/main/binary-armel/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/quantal/universe/binary-armel/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/quantal/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/quantal/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: построй билдрут

Answer (score 0):

Но ведь вполне конкретно написано:

```
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main armel Packages                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

Нет этого репозитария! Точнее, URL в DNS ещё остался, но физически этого адреса уже нет.

Comment: Он действительный. Я могу как пропинготовать его, так и попасть на сайт через этот ip

Comment: сайт то может и действительный, но вот нужного пути там нет

Comment: @idabsent, сами убедитесь: http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/ — для quantal репозиториев там нет. в old-releases-ах есть: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/